# laravel 8 error en migraciones

Tags: php, laravel

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `post` add constraint `post_id_tag_foreign` foreign key (`id_tag`) references `post_tag` (`id`))

Migracion post

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->longText('descripcion', 400);
        $table->string('imagen');
        $table->string('extract');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_tag');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_user');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_categori');
        
        //llaves foraneas
        $table->foreign('id_tag')->references('id')->on('post_tag');
        $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('id_categori')->references('id')->on('categori');

        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Migracion post_tag

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_post');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_tag');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('posts_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tags_id');

        $table->foreign('tags_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
        $table->foreign('id_post')->references('id')->on('post');
        
        $table->timestamps();



    });
}
```

Comment: ¿en qué orden estás ejecutando las migraciones?, es decir ¿cuál se esta ejecutando antes y cuál después?

Comment: primero se ejecuta la migración de post

Comment: No puedes intentar vincular una llave foránea con una llave primaria de una tabla existente, dicho lo anterior entonces es tan simple como modificar ese orden y considerar que esto es mas un fallo relacionado del lado de mysql que de Laravel en si

Comment: de paso, el post no tiene por qué referenciar la tabla de paso hacia los tags. Es la tabla de paso la que no puede tener registros vinculados a posts o tags inexistentes.

Comment: Debes organizar el orden en que se ejecutan las migraciones. Hay una tabla que depende de otra y esa tabla no puede crearse primero.